# How do I traverse through this tree(not a binary search tree)?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

NOTE: I used recursion

I want to traverse through this tree(all the nodes/objects) and maybe add them to an array or tweak them a little bit or something.
I was trying to create a chess gameboard(not even sure I'm on the right track).
Each block on the board is an object(node) with properties such as, an array with the x and y coordinates of the block, the block on its right, left, top and bottom.
Here is the code for the tree:

```
 This function creates all the blocks on the board
function Node(pos, top = null, right = null, left = null, bottom = null) {
  this.pos = pos;
  this.top = top;
  this.right = right;
  this.left = left;
  this.bottom = bottom;
}


This function creates the gameboard
function buildBoard(x = 1, y = 1) {
  if(x == 9 || y == 9 || x <= 0 || y <= 0) return null
  else {
    const root = new Node([x, y])
    root.right = buildBoard(x += 1, y);
    x -= 1;
    root.top = buildBoard(x, y += 1);
    return root
  }
}
```

I tried traversing through this tree as if it was a binary tree and it sorta worked.
Since this tree is basically all the blocks on a chess board(8x8), the total number of blocks should be 64 but when I traverse through it the same way I would a binary tree, it gives me thousands of nodes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a tree. It is a cyclic graph.

The main problem is that your code will create the node with coordinates 2, 2 twice, because it gets there via two routes: by going right first and then down, or by going down first and then right. This gets worse the further away the created node is from the origin: for every possible path consisting of right/down steps, a node will be created, resulting in a multitude of nodes that have the same coordinates.

Here is how you could do it properly:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(pos, top=null, right=null) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = null;
        this.left = null;
        if (top) top.bottom = this; // back reference
        if (right) right.left = this; // back reference
    }
}


function buildBoard() {
    const row = Array(10).fill(null);
    for (let y = 8; y; y--) {
        for (let x = 8; x; x--) {
            row[x] = new Node([x, y], row[x], row[x + 1]);
        }
    }
    return row[1]; // cell at [1, 1]
}

let a1 = buildBoard(); // Returns the bottom-left square of the board

// Verify that two different paths to the same coordinates, lead to the
// same node:
let d3 = a1.right.right.right.top.top;
console.log("Does alternative path lead to d3?:", 
            d3 === a1.top.right.right.right.right.top.left);
console.log("coordinates of d3 [x,y]:", 
            JSON.stringify(d3.pos));
```